# I am working on a microsoft flow which updates a column on the basis of another column

Tags: calculated-column, sharepoint-list, power-automate, formatting, column-formatting

Here is the screenshot of the source and destination:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the source and destination:]1. I am working on a flow which updates a column **SME Comment CK** on the basis of another column **SME Comment**. These columns are multiline text. but when the column gets updated I can see the html tags in it. How can I update the column as it is in **SME Comment**. PFA the screenshot for reference.[image]

2. Also, I have another column **resource name** which has data in the format - Patrick_Jay, Eric_D_Dsouza. I want these to be updated in another column **Resource email id** in the format-Patrick.Jay@gmail.com, Eric.d.Dsouza@gmail.com. This not need to be via flow. is this possible in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshot of flow:

[image]

Screenshot of Result:

[image]

Screenshot of Sharepoint list columns:

[image]

1. See screen shot from Power automate how to copy multiline (not sure how you managed to get the html tags in there!). I am assuming here that you are not using http request to update the columns. Here we are copying the multilines from the column Source to the column Target.

[image]

[image]

2. You can make the **Resource email id** a calculated column and put in the following formular:

=IF(ISBLANK([resource name]), "", [resource name]&"@gmail")

this will append the "@gmail" to the resource name or leave the field empty if resource name field is empty.

Comment: Hello @RuneBH, thank you so much for your response! :) ohh it got resolved now. Earlier the source column was an enhanced rich text and destination column was a plain text. corrected it to enhanced rich text. But now I have another issue. I have a condition in flow where it checks if the source column is equal to the destination column then send an email. but it always results as false.

Comment: Hi @HRY After updating the destination column you need to get file properties again and use those in the condition as it will otherwise not have the updated properties. That might be the issue :)

Comment: Actually I am working on a sharepoint list. what should I use in place of file properties in case of a sharepoint list?

Comment: That would be Get Item.

Comment: Hello @RuneBH, the two columns look a bit different. Destination text has wrapped the text. Source: 3/11: Validating 3/11: Validating 3/11: Validating Destination: 3/11: Validating 3/11: Validating 3/11: Validating can this cause the source and destination doesn't match resulting as false. Is there any way to wrap the text of the Source as well using some expresssion? have added the screenshot of the data reflecting in source and destination in the main query.

Comment: I just tried it out with a source column with line breaks, different font colors, indents etc. It will copy just fine and the condition result set to "true". Perhaps post a screen shot of your flow :)

Comment: Thank you @RuneBH for all your efforts in helping me. :) really appreciate. Have attached the screenshots of Flow, Result and Sharepoint list columns.

Comment: Alrite - you added the screen shots to my answer, thats a bit messy, but i get it :)

Comment: Perhaps try to create a list element and manually insert a value in both columns in order to verify that you condition works. If it does then it must be something in your copy columns values that are not working. 

If this is the case I would check that columns are indeed of the same type and with same settings. If this is looking alrite then I would check if your flows (I sense that perhaps there are multiple flows running on the list) are not interfering with each other.